# Contact form phone number validation error PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I want to add contact form phone number field. Some countries have 12 digit and some countries have 11 digit numbers. So i want to required this field min. digit 10 and max 12. Herewith i mentioned validation code.

```
/* Phone */
function validatePhone($phone) {
    $error_text = "Phone format: (xxx) xxxx-xxxxx";
    $phone_template = "/^\([0-9]{3}\) [0-9]{4}-[0-9]{5}$/";
    return (preg_match($phone_template, $phone) !== 1) ? $error_text : "valid";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this,

```
function validatePhone($phone) {
   $error_text = "Phone format: (xxx)-xxxx-xxxxx";
   $remove = array("(", ")", " ", "-");
   if (preg_match('/^\d{11,12}$/', str_replace($remove, '', $phone))) {
     // valid

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this suffice?

```
function validatePhone($number) {
  $error = "Phone format: (xxx) xxxx-xxxxx";
  $template = "/^\([0-9]{3}\) [0-9]{4}-[0-9]{3,5}$/";
  return (preg_match($template, $number) !== 1) ? $error : "valid";
}
```

Or if you want to allow the last 2 digits to be anywhere:

```
function validatePhone($number) {
  $error = "Phone format: (xxx) xxxx-xxxxx";
  $template = "/^\([0-9]{3,5}\) [0-9]{4,6}-[0-9]{3,5}$/";
  $result = (preg_match($template, $number) !== 1) ? $error : "valid";
  return $result !== "valid" || strlen($number) > 16 ? $error : $result;
}
```